# Issue with derivation of $\nabla \times\nabla{\phi} =0 $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

To prove that $\nabla \times\nabla{\phi} =0 $.  The argument defines that $\nabla{\phi} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \hat{i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}} \hat{j} + \frac{\partial}{\partial{z}} \hat{k}$. But shouldn't the dot product result in a scalar and not a vector? Though If it did result in a scalar, one cannot take the cross product of a scalar and a vector, so why does the dot product result in a vector here ?

Comment: The gradient $\nabla$ is *defined* as the vector operator $\nabla \equiv i \partial_x + j\partial_y + k\partial_z$ so when acting on a scalar it gives a vector. Only if you dot it with a vector you would get a scalar e.g. $\nabla\cdot \vec{A}$ (but that is not the case here as I said: $\phi$ is a scalar).

Comment: I see thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You've conflated the *gradient* $\nabla\phi$ of a scalar $\phi$ with the *divergence* $\nabla\cdot V$ of a vector $V$. Gradients are vectors; divergences are scalars.